# Restrict Google maps map to show one country

Tags: google-maps

I have to create a map with multiple locations from one country. I need to display only that country in Google Maps and remove other. If someone knows how to do that, write the solution here.

Thanks.

[google maps restrict to one country](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SWuS.png)

Answer (score -2):

You could take a screenshot of the country and remove the neighboring countries with Paint or Gimp. With Gimp you have more possibilities, if you use multiple layers you can make sure that neighboring countries are not completely removed, but are displayed paler.

Comment: This will not work for me because I need the map to work.